# infinite-scroll with button in angular 8

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement infinite scroll with button.

code:

```
<div class="search-results"
      infinite-scroll
      [infiniteScrollDistance]="scrollDistance"
      [infiniteScrollUpDistance]="scrollUpDistance"
      [infiniteScrollThrottle]="throttle"
      (scrolled)="onScrollDown()"
      (scrolledUp)="onUp()">
  <p *ngFor="let i of array">
   bharathi {{  i }}
  </p>
</div>
```

I am able to get load the server content by infinite scrolling. But I need this with "Load more" button.
When I click on "Load More" button I need to fetch the next 20 records and append the same to the infinite scroll and so on.

Can I know whether this can be done with ngx-infinite-scroll module?

Comment: Why do you need infinite scroll then?

Comment: @Ivan Then how can I append the content without replacing the the existing content? Suppose I have already showing 10 items, when I click on "show more" button I need to append the items to the existing content

Answer (score 0):

The button "Load more" really defies the purpose of the infinite scroll. If "Load more" button is at the bottom of the page AND you've implemented the infinite scroll, the user will never get to that button.

If all you need is to append the new content without replacing the existing content, do this:

```
array = array.concat(new_data)
```

Angular will correctly display the updated content of an array.
Also check out this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jp-c6_pxAns